# Getting Argument out of range during pathfinding Coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, path-finding, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm new to using coroutines and am getting and out of range array error when running this function. I'm hoping it is a simple problem contained within this function, perhaps I am yielding at the wrong point, or need to use path.count -1.

```
public void UpdatePath() {
    the.pathFinder.FindPath (my);

    Vector3[] pathVectors = new Vector3[my.path.Count + 1];

    pathVectors [0] = (Vector3)my.transform.position;

    if (my.path.Count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < my.path.Count; i++)
            pathVectors [i + 1] = my.path [i].transform.position;
    }

    my.pathLine.SetVertexCount (my.path.Count + 1);
    my.pathLine.SetPositions(pathVectors);

    StopCoroutine("FollowPath");
    StartCoroutine("FollowPath");
}

IEnumerator FollowPath() {

    Vector3 currentWayPoint = my.path [0].transform.position;

    while (true) {

        Vector2 heading = the.Heading (my.transform.position, currentWayPoint);

        if (heading.sqrMagnitude < 0.4) {
            targetIndex++;
            if (targetIndex >= my.path.Count) {
                print ("On yield break - TargetIndex is " + targetIndex + " and my.path.Count is " + my.path.Count);
                yield break;
            }
            print ("On assigning currentWayPoint - TargetIndex is " + targetIndex + " and my.path.Count is " + my.path.Count);
            currentWayPoint = my.path [targetIndex].transform.position;
        }

        my.pathGoal = ((heading).sqrMagnitude > 1f) ? heading.normalized * my.speed : heading * my.speed;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I have put in a print log to check targetIndex against my.path.Count. To my understanding, in the second print log, the targetIndex should not be able to be equal to or greater than the my.path.Count and yet in the log, I'm getting "On assigning currentWayPoint - TargetIndex is 1 and my.path.Count is 1". I realise this is why I'm getting the out of range exception, but I don't understand how the code is reachable if the TargetIndex is equal to the my.path.Count. Is it possible for something else to happen between the yield break; line and the print log? Do coroutines run simultaneously with other code that could conflict?.

Comment: I tested your code, it works just fine. At least the problem is not in the methods you posted.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with coroutines.

You're trying to access member with index higher than the number of array elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < my.path.Count; i++)
    pathVectors [i + 1] = my.path [i].transform.position; // will fail on i = path.Count
```

Moreover, compiler tells you at what point in the code this exception happens, which should pretty easily lead you to a conclusion you have already reached:

> need to use `path.count -1`

It's always a good idea to try what's on your mind in code to see if that works, before asking questions on SO.

Also, the `if` statement around this code is meaningless.

Comment: How can i = path.Count if i<path.Count?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have tried changing that part and it makes no difference, only breaks the functionality. The out of index is not happening on this line, it's happening on the...

            currentWayPoint = my.path [targetIndex].transform.position;

line, even though the line before it breaks if targetIndex is => my.path.Count. Very strange.